# Как узнать, с какого дня начинается неделя для текущей локали системы?

Tags: c, дата, кроссплатформенность, локаль

Требуется вывести в консоль календарь на месяц, для чего необходимо знать день, с которого начинается неделя. В С в структуре времени по умолчанию день недели хранится в формате 0-6, где 0 = воскресенье. Интересует независимость от платформы для данного приложения. Как корректно получить системную локаль и узнать первый день недели для нее?
Возможно есть сторонняя кроссплатформенная библиотека или же придется делать под API разных систем?
Сделать нужно на чистом С.

Comment: Решение найдено.
Этих функций в чистом Си нет, поэтому пришлось под каждую платформу использовать ее API.

Для Windows -> windows.h, winnls.h -> функция GetLocaleInfo:
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK,...) - для определения первого дня.
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SABBREVDAYNAME1,...) - для определения названия в локале дня недели.

Для POSIX -> langinfo.h locale.h-> setlocale(LC_TYME,"");
nl_langinfo(_NL_TIME_FIRST_WEEKDAY); //первый день недели
nl_langinfo(ABDAY_1);//название дня
и т.д.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Меня вот что интересует. ОС Windows декларируют POSIX-совместимость. Поэтому, мне кажется, возможно обойтись одним, POSIX-совместимым кодом.

Comment: POSIX-совместимость не ограничивает ОС в расширении своих возможностей

Comment: Соглашусь, но POSIX на то и есть, чтобы быть везде....

Comment: Делаете тестовое задание для Школы iOS разработчиков? ;-)
http://gyazo.com/912ae1ad78f192b5f8083edd1a3dfc5e

Comment: Оно)) Уже давно сделал)

Comment: И как, пригласили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнать название текущей локали - `setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);`. Вместо `LC_ALL` Вам может быть лучше взять `LC_TIME`.

Environment's default locale - `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");`

Параметры текущкй локали - `struct lconv *curloc = localeconv();`. Подробности в locale.h

По идее Вам надо вызвать `setlocale(LC_TIME,"");` и использовать `localtime()`, но
в реальной жизни проблема в том, что локаль часто новрмально не настроена.

Comment: По-моему, у ТС главный вопрос был не в том. А нужен, как мне кажется, первый день в неделе для соответствующей локали (в России - понедельник, в сша - воскресенье, например)

Comment: 2rasmisha Вы правильно меня поняли.

Comment: На самом деле интересный вопрос. Сводится к такому - *Как по локали определить какой из форматов %u или %w надо использовать в strftime() ?*

В Win API надо смотреть функцию GetLocaleInfo. В Linux аналога не нашел.

Comment: Только, если я правильно, понял - не %u и %w, а %U и %W

Comment: Я не силен в линуксе, но вариант с   
    locale -k first_weekday  
  
на некоторых локалях точно работает.

Comment: @gecube, именно %u и %w

    %u     The day of the week as a decimal, range 1 to 7, Monday being 1.
    %w     The day of the week as a decimal, range 0 to 6, Sunday being 0.
    %U     The  week number of the current year ... starting with the first Sunday ...
    %W     The  week number of the current year ... starting with the first Monday ...

из `man 3 strftime`

Comment: А эти параметры везде поддерживаются, т.к. в разных версиях компиляторов они то есть все, то нет части?

Comment: Посмотрел в MinGW нет %u (ничего не выводит)

Формат "%w-%W-%u-%U" выводит в MinGW (Windows XP)

    locale: C
    buf: [2-28--28]
    locale: Russian_Russia.1251
    buf: [2-28--28]
    locale: English_United States.1252
    buf: [2-28--28]

в linux

    locale: C
    buf: [2-28-2-28]
    locale: ru_RU.UTF-8
    buf: [2-28-2-28]
    locale: en_US.utf-8
    buf: [2-28-2-28]

Так что, толку от этого - ноль. 

Если для приложения это важно, то надо делать *свою "локализацию"*. Та еще морока.

Answer (score 1):

Вот дурь, честное слово. Я тут провел маленькое исследование и выяснил, что нужно тогда поддерживать возможность указать ЛЮБОЕ начало недели. Например, в некоторых странах неделю начинают с субботы (!). Так сделано у арабов. Но они и пишут своей вязью справа налево, да? А завтра в какой-нибудь Камбодже примут стандарт, что будут считать недели со среды и что тогда делать!? по вопросу - в Си (голом) я не нашел возможности узнать с какого дня начинается неделя, да и нужно ли это действительно? Может проще сделать по-другому? Например, просто занести в конфигурационный файл программы возможность изменения этой опции или автодетект по типу локали (US -> начинаем с ВС, RU -> начинаем с ПН). Я даже табличку соответствий по странам нашел:

```
<weekData>
<minDays count="1" territories="001 GU UM US VI"/>
<minDays count="4" territories="AD AN AT AX BE BG CH CZ DE DK EE ES FI FJ FO FR GB GF GP GR IE IS IT LI LT LU MC MQ NL NO PL PT RE SE SK SM VA"/>
<!--
Note, this firstDay is for the first day of the week in a calendar page view.
-->
<!--
The first workday of the week (after the weekend) is distinct, and can be determined as the day after the weekendEnd day.
-->
<firstDay day="mon" territories="001 AD AI AL AM AN AT AX AZ BA BE BG BM BN CH CL CM CR CY CZ DE DK EC EE ES FI FJ FO FR GB GE GF GP GR HR HU IS IT KG KZ LB LI LK LT LU LV MC MD ME MK MN MQ MY NL NO PL PT RE RO RS RU SE SI SK SM TJ TM TR UA UY UZ VA VN"/>
<firstDay day="fri" territories="BD MV"/>
<firstDay day="sat" territories="AE AF BH DJ DZ EG IQ IR JO KW LY MA OM QA SA SD SY YE"/>
<firstDay day="sun" territories="AG AR AS AU BR BS BT BW BY BZ CA CN CO DM DO ET GT GU HK HN ID IE IL IN JM JP KE KH KR LA MH MM MO MT MX MZ NI NP NZ PA PE PH PK PR PY SG SV TH TN TT TW UM US VE VI WS ZA ZW"/>
<firstDay day="sun" territories="GB" alt="variant" references="Shorter Oxford Dictionary (5th edition, 2002)"/>
<weekendStart day="thu" territories="AF DZ IR OM SA YE"/>
<weekendStart day="fri" territories="AE BH EG IL IQ JO KW LY MA QA SD SY TN"/>
<weekendStart day="sat" territories="001"/>
<weekendStart day="sun" territories="IN"/>
<weekendEnd day="fri" territories="AF DZ IR OM SA YE"/>
<weekendEnd day="sat" territories="AE BH EG IL IQ JO KW LY MA QA SD SY TN"/>
<weekendEnd day="sun" territories="001"/>
</weekData>
```

И самое главное - проверить в какой стране (локали) мы находимся можно через переменную окружения `LANG`. А ее можно вычитать через `extern char * *__environ;` Либо использовать ф-цию [`getenv()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/)

Comment: Так как эта информация может обновляться, есть смысл сделать ссылку на актуальный файл: [supplementalData.xml](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml).

Читать территорию из переменных окружения как-то не очень кроссплатформенно.

Comment: Вообще-то, как я понял, именно стандарт POSIX предписывает держать переменную окружения LANG.

Answer (score 0):

Очень интересный вопрос, на который, признаться, с ходу ответа не имел. Поиск дал решение для POSIX-систем, основанное на применении фукнции nl_langinfo: [пост форума источника](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/149591-how-do-i-get-first-day-week-current-locale.html#post1114532), [man](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html). Сейчас на работе, вечером попробую проверить на работоспособность.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на мой же вопрос на английском форуме )